# How to show additional wp_postmeta in the Media Library of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin where additional meta informations are saved in the wp_postmeta database. This works fine so far.

But how can I display this information in the media library? I can't find any action to hook on.

Eg.: if there is a video and I saved the resolution in wp_postmeta, then the media library should show the video information + a field with the video resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `manage_media_columns` and `manage_media_custom_column` hooks. First, register two extra columns for the media library:

```
add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', 'so16520837_manage_media_columns', 10, 2 );
function so16520837_manage_media_columns( $columns )
{
    $columns['vid_info'] = __( 'Video Info', 'plugin_txt_domain' );
    $columns['vid_reso'] = __( 'Video Resolution', 'plugin_txt_domain' );
    return $columns;
}
```

Then add the appropriate post meta, e.g.:

```
add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'so16520837_manage_media_custom_column', 10, 2 );
function so16520837_manage_media_custom_column( $column_name, $id )
{
    switch ( $column_name )
    {
        case 'vid_info' :
            echo get_post_meta( $id, 'my_vid_info', true );
        break;

        case 'vid_reso' :
            echo get_post_meta( $id, 'my_vid_reso', true );
        break;

        default :
        break;
    }
}
```